# Circles in $\mathrm{mod}\ 3$ "XOR-triangles"

Tags: combinatorics, geometry, modular-arithmetic

This question is about a slight generalization of "XOR-triangles", which is the name the OEIS gives to the construction discussed in the MathOverflow question "[Number triangle](https://mathoverflow.net/q/359138/104733)."

> The first line of the triangle is the binary representation (without any extra zeros padded). The next row of triangle is obtained by [... adding] two consecutive digits of above row [modulo $2$], and so on until completion.
> $$
> 1~~~~1~~~~0~~~~1~~~~0~~~~1\\
> 0~~~~1~~~~1~~~~1~~~~1\\
> 1~~~~0~~~~0~~~~0\\
> 1~~~~0~~~~0\\
> 1~~~~0\\
> 1
> $$

If you color the $1$s black and the $0$s white, the rotationally symmetric XOR triangles look like this:
[image: Examples of XOR-triangles]
*from Michael De Vlieger on OEIS sequence [A334556](https://oeis.org/A334556); click for a higher resolution image.*

---

### Rotationally symmetric "$\mathrm{mod}\ 3$" triangles.

If we do the same construction only $\mathrm{mod}\ 3$ instead of $\mathrm{mod}\ 2$, and where the top row can now have $0$s, $1$s, and $2$s, with the $0$s colored black and the $1$s and $2$s colored white, you get pictures like the following:

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

These are with $401$ cells in the top row.

#### The observation

In the first, second, and fourth triangles, there appears to be patterns that look like circles if you squint. (I've drawn over them in red to help you see what I'm talking about.)

[image]
[image]
[image]

As far as I can tell, these are "real" circles as opposed to graphics artifacts or optical illusions. Moreover, they don't appear to be hexagons, which wouldn't surprise me as much.

Is there a nice explanation for why such accurate-looking circles appear from this construction?

Comment: Because there only exists points of the triangular grid, no true circles can exist there. I guess that it is about hexagon's exhibiting full $D_3$-symmetry plus a few extra points enhancing the illusion.

Comment: They all appear much rounder to me than hexagons!

Comment: how about 12 sides  the apothem perimeter ratio is within  2.4% of 2 Pi

Comment: I agree that I couldn’t tell a 12-gon apart from a circle in this context, but having a 12-gon appear is surprising too, since you can’t draw a regular 12-gon with vertices on the triangular grid.

Comment: WOW! This is cool.